# how to upload image directly from client side to server

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, gwtupload

I am using gwt web application. I want to provide users, the functionality to print screen and press Ctrl+v , for which i have provided an image element in which image will be set on pressing Ctrl+V. Now i want to upload that Image to server. I do not want to use the Up loader which select files from File system and then upload the file.

Comment: send the image to the server , use ajax may be

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a [servlet in Tomcat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)

Then send the image to the servlet using [FormData](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-html5-wrappers/source/browse/trunk/src/com/pixeljet/html5/client/FormData.java?r=2) and [XMLHTTPRequest2](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-xmlhttprequest2/source/browse/src/com/google/gwt/xhr/client/XMLHTTPRequest2.java?r=1ca8108b439f38a945223eeffd1343e9f48d5e44)

You need to getthe image from the DOM, and then do something like that:

```
String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "UploadFileServlet?sid=" + AppHelper.remoteService.getSessionID();
XMLHTTPRequest2 xhr = (XMLHTTPRequest2) XMLHTTPRequest2.create();

xhr.open("POST", url);


FormData formData = FormData.create();
formData.append("file", imagedata);


xhr.setOnReadyStateChange(new ReadyStateChangeHandler()
{

    //@Override
    public void onReadyStateChange(XMLHttpRequest xhr)
    {
        /////Window.alert(" " + xhr.getStatus());

        // When the form submission is successfully completed, this event is
        // fired. Assuming the service returned a response of type text/html,
        // we can get the result text here (see the FormPanel documentation for
        // further explanation).
        //Window.alert(event.getResults());

        String result = xhr.getResponseText();

        if(result.equals("ok"))
        {
            Window.alert("File uploaded");

        }
        else
        {
            Window.alert(result);
        }
    }
});

xhr.send(formData);
```

**This is the FormData class**

```
public class FormData extends JavaScriptObject {
  //default constructor
  //see more at http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#formdata
  protected FormData() {

  }

  /**
   * add a pair of value to form.
   * <p>
   * See <a href="http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#formdata"
   * >http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#formdata</a>.
   * 
   * @param name the name to be add
   * @param value the value to be add
   */
  public final native void append(String name, String value) /*-{
    this.append(name, value);
  }-*/;

  public final native void append(String name, JavaScriptObject value) /*-{
    this.append(name, value);
  }-*/;

  /**
   * Creates an XMLHttpRequest object.
   * 
   * @return the created object
   */
  public static native FormData create() /*-{
    return new FormData();
  }-*/;
}
```

**And this is XMLHttpRequest2 class**

```
public class XMLHTTPRequest2 extends XMLHttpRequest {

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  protected XMLHTTPRequest2() {

  }

  /**
   * Initiates a request with data.  If there is no data, specify null.
   * <p>
   * See <a href="http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#dom-xmlhttprequest-send"
   * >http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#dom-xmlhttprequest-send</a>.
   * 
   * @param requestData the data to be sent with the request
   */
  public final native <T> void send(T requestData) /*-{
    this.send(requestData);
  }-*/;
}
```

Comment: Is formdata and XMLHTTPRequest2 supported as i am not able to use them ?

Comment: These are GWT wrappers for Javascript, I've posted some links for GWT wrappers. To make the wrappers yoursel you need to JSNI, these classes are not part of the GWT

Comment: With JSNI you can use in GWT native javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this: http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/

You can get the file and then use a multipart/form-data request to upload it with a servlet as explained here http://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-jquery-file-upload/.

Comment: http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/ -  this do not work in chromium ,any idea why it does not?